# (From Milne) Show that the ﬁxed ﬁeld of $H$ is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p})$ when $p=1 mod 4$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-p})$ when $p=3 mod 4$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

This is an exercise in Milne's notes:
[image]

[image]

Here is the question with an answer. But I find myself hardly understand it. especially the part that if $i\in H$, $iH=H$ and $i(G\setminus H)=G\setminus H$. And I do not under tand the sentence with the "$\Leftrightarrow$". I think in above argument it has proved $i+j=0,i\in H,j\in G\setminus H\Leftrightarrow -1 \text{ is not a square mod p}$
I am so confused. So what is going on here. May I please ask for an explicit argument? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an error on the line with the $\iff$.  It should read $\iff -1\, \text{is a nonsquare }\bmod p$  As far as the $i\in H$ and that.  $H$ is a subgroup.  If $i\in H, iH=H$  It's trivial.

Comment: If $G$ is any group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $h \in G$, then the map $G \rightarrow G$ given by $g \mapsto hg$ is a *bijection* from $G$ to itself: it switches around the elements of $G$.  If you further assume that $h$ lies in $H$, then of course this map switches around the elements of $H$.  So obviously, it has to switch around the elements in $G - H$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think carefully about what some of these things are.  $G=(\Bbb{Z}/(p))^{\times},$ a cyclic (multiplicative) group.  $H$ is the subgroup of index 2 in $G$, so that means $H$ consists of elements which are squares and $G\setminus H$ nonsquares.  So when he says that "$-1=i^{-1}j$, which is a nonsquare;" he's appealing to the earlier observation that $i(G\setminus H)=(G\setminus H)$.  You're taking an element of $H$ times an element of $G\setminus H$, so you must get an element of $G\setminus H$ which is a non-square.  $-1$ is a non-square $\bmod p$ iff $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I find the last sentence of your argument not such obvious. Could you please explain why $-1$ is a non-square mod $p$ iff $p=3mod4$?

Comment: $-1$ is a nonsquare$\bmod p$  for $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$ is because if it were, $G$ would have an element of order $4$.  But $4\not | (p-1)$, so this is impossible.  For the other direction consider the contrapositive.  If $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$, then $\Bbb{Z}/(p))^{\times}$ contains an element of order $4$, call it $\alpha$.  Then $\alpha^4-1\equiv 0\bmod p$.  But $\alpha\neq 1,-1$ so  $\alpha^2+1\equiv 0\bmod p$.  Hence $\alpha$ is a square root of $-1$

Comment: Got it. Thanks! But knowing that I still find the proof such implicit that can hardly be followed the proof below. He use sentences instead of explicit equations to explain things and I can hardly see what he is actually talking about.If possible, could you please explain what the author is mean in the following argument? Or if there exists some simpler way to do that...

Comment: The end comes down to counting the number of terms in the double sum.  We've concluded that each power of $\zeta$ occurs the same number of times.  For every $p-1$ powers of $\zeta -1$ is added to the sum (like $\omega + \omega^2 = -1$ for a cube root of unity).  For the $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ there are $((p-1)/2)^2$ terms which gives $\alpha \beta = -(p-1)/4$ (note sign error in solution)  For $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ calculation is similar but we need to take into account the $i+j=0$ terms which will contribute $1$ to the sum.  $(p-3)/4$ should be $(p-2)/4$.  The polynomial is $x^2+x+(p+1)/4$

Comment: Sorry I notice that I cannot see the implication from "Then $α^4−1≡0modp$. But $α≠1,−1$" to "$ α^2+1≡0modp$." Why is that true?

Comment: $\alpha$ satisfies the equation $x^4-1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$.  We know (since $\alpha$ has order $4$) that $\alpha\neq \pm1$, so $\alpha$ has to be a root of $x^2+1$